# Printing with Cups

Tags: printing, cups

I can print a test page from Cups. But if I print from e.g. Google Chrome, it is not working and Cups will also not know show any new jobs. The printer is on the network. How can I debug this?

Comment: `lpstat -W completed` What does this show when you finish printing from `google-chrome`?

Comment: It won't show up in `lpstat -W completed`. It will also not print from `google-chrome`. I think this was not clear.

Comment: Any other idea how I could understand where the documents get lost?

Comment: Have you checked the cups log? In `/var/log`

Comment: The logs show when I remove and add a new printer. They show the test page that I've been printing from Cups. But they don't show anything that I print otherwise.